# How do I store the html string that my GetRequest task retrieves as a variable?

Tags: c#, discord, httprequest, httpresponse

What the title says basically. I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff so I'm not sure how to store the string after it's retrieved. My current goal is making a discord bot that monitors a webpage for updates. Any criticism about the code below is also appreciated!

```
[Command("anime")]
        public async Task Anime()
        {
            await GetRequest("https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/");           

            async static Task GetRequest(string url)
            {
                using (HttpClient webclient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await webclient.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            // HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;

                            Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                            // Console.WriteLine(headers);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you want to store the data? In a File or in a Database?

Comment: @Tomsen My fault for not clarifying. I'm trying to store it as a variable so I can compare it to a new html string that I retrieve.

Comment: I'm afraid I need some more details on that, since it is already stored in a variable called `mycontent`.

Comment: @Earhojnod Do you want to use `mycontent` outside of the function? If so, you would need to return it from the function instead of writing it to the console.

Comment: @Earhojnod If you find the answer be sure to post it in here so future visitors will have it too.

Comment: @RoyCohen Good idea, was trying to figure out how to accept your post as an answer but posting my solution works too.

Answer (score 0):

With some help I came up with this. I'm able to store and call the string as `website` now. I just took the `GetRequest` method out of the main Anime task that I'm calling and used `Task<string>` to indicate I want a return.

```
[Command("anime")]
        public async Task Anime()
        {
           string website = await GetRequest("https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/");

        }

        private static async Task<string> GetRequest(string url)
        {
            using (HttpClient webclient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await webclient.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        // HttpContentHeaders headers = content.Headers;

                        // Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                        return mycontent;
                        // Console.WriteLine(headers);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```